# jquery upload file passar variavel php para JavaScript

Tags: php, jquery

estou usando este plugin [JQUERY UPLOAD FILE](http://hayageek.com/docs/jquery-upload-file.php) e esta tudo ok com os upload estou incrementando funcao de criar diretorio e upar dentro delas porem nao estou conseguindo passar a variavel id do php para a pagina que faz o serviço meu codigo esta assim:

paginaenviar.php

```
$id = $_GET['id'];
if(is_dir("../imagens/$id")) {
echo "diretorio ja existe";
}
else {
mkdir ("../imagens/$id", 0700 );
echo "diretorio criado";
}

<div id="mulitplefileuploader">Upload</div>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function()
{
var settings = {
    url: "upload.php?id=<?php echo $id ?>",
    dragDrop:true,
    fileName: "myfile",
    allowedTypes:"jpg,png,gif,doc,pdf,zip", 
    returnType:"json",
  onSuccess:function(files,data,xhr)
    {
       // alert((data));
    },
    showDelete:true,
    deleteCallback: function(data,pd)
 {
    for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++)
    {
        $.post("uploadDelete.php",{op:"delete",name:data[i]},
        function(resp, textStatus, jqXHR)
        {
            //Show Message  
            $("#status").append("<div>File Deleted</div>");      
        });
     }      
    pd.statusbar.hide(); //You choice to hide/not.

}
}
var uploadObj = $("#mulitplefileuploader").uploadFile(settings);


});
```

upload.php

```html
$id = $_GET['id'];

$output_dir = "../imagens/$id";
if(isset($_FILES["myfile"]))
{
 $ret = array();

 $error =$_FILES["myfile"]["error"];
 //You need to handle  both cases
 //If Any browser does not support serializing of multiple files using FormData() 
 if(!is_array($_FILES["myfile"]["name"])) //single file
 {
    $fileName = $_FILES["myfile"]["name"];
   move_uploaded_file($_FILES["myfile"]["tmp_name"],$output_dir.$fileName);
     $ret[]= $fileName;
 }
 else  //Multiple files, file[]
 {
   $fileCount = count($_FILES["myfile"]["name"]);
   for($i=0; $i < $fileCount; $i++)
   {
    $fileName = $_FILES["myfile"]["name"][$i];
  move_uploaded_file($_FILES["myfile"]["tmp_name"][$i],$output_dir.$fileName);
    $ret[]= $fileName;
   }
 
 }
    echo json_encode($ret);
 }
```

como passar a variavel?

Comment: Sempre que leio Java quando alguém se refere a JavaScript, os meus olhos doem. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Meu problema foi que estava faltando uma barra:

```
$output_dir = "../imagens/$id";
```

Adicionando ela:

```
$output_dir = "../imagens/$id/";
```

Funcionou

Comment: Melhorei a redação da sua resposta, agora você pode marcá-la como aceita.